# Closed-system power-generation using waterwheels

Tags: energy

I'm not a physicist, and this question is bugging me .. :)

Is it possible to create a closed power-generation system, using upper and lower water-reservoirs where a continuous flow from the upper to the lower turns a waterwheel (or series of..) with an elongated axle(s) to which several generators are attached with bevel-gears, by using the power generated by some of the generators to pump water back to the upper reservoir at the same rate as the outflow, and the remaining generators feed the grid?

[edit]
Based on the comments and answers:
(and I'm not fooling about, I really want to understand)
Say you have one waterwheel with one generator attached which gives say 50% efficiency (can return 50% of the used water to the upper reservoir, all friction, heat-loss, etc, taken into account); Now you add 2 more generators to the waterwheel's elongated axle: the output of two of these generators will return 100% of the water, and the output of the third is available for use. There can be a cascading set of waterwheels each with generators attached..
Why would this not work, what am I not seeing?

[PS:]Wasn't it Archimedes who said something about a long-enough lever and a place to stand and he will move the earth? Meaning that a small input (muscle-power in this case) *can* have much larger output.
A waterwheel is nothing less than a lever, and so are the gears, ...

Comment: Do you mean something which generates energy from nothing, basically?

Comment: [Pumped hydro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity) is possible.  [Perpetual motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) not possible.

Comment: @Jodes: no, - gravity ...

Comment: To use the energy from flow of water to put the water back, with energy to spare, is creating energy from nothing. That is perpetual motion, which is impossible

Comment: @Jodes: even with several wheels where you can adjust the radiuses (==lever-lengths), as well as that of the bevel-gears?

Comment: Impossible. It's like expecting a car's brakes to be able to use the energy to then accelerate the car again; it's not possible, which is why cars use fuel. You can re-use *some* of the energy, but not all. Certainly not create extra energy. In most conversions of energy, heat is the form of energy that inefficient processes lose it to. Your gears, electronics and the water itself would get warmer (from very slightly to significantly warmer)

Comment: Using leverage you can do things like increase the speed/distance, at the cost of the amount of force, or vice-versa. Not both. There will still be energy lost, most of which would be as heat. Using the most rigid materials, and the best forms of lubrication or ball bearings etc would help, but nothing will be 100% efficient. Certainly not above 100%! Physicists have known this for a long time. It is the foundation of modern physics. Without this knowledge, we wouldn't have transistors, or car engines, we wouldn't even have had steam engines.

Comment: Around 1850 Rudolf Clausius and William Thomson (Kelvin) established the First Law of thermodynamics - that total energy is conserved

Comment: @NickAlexeev: if one wheel is used, yes, but with several, re-using one quantity of water?

Comment: @slashmais stop this madness and wake up. It's got nothing to do with EE - just think about it - it's common sense that you can't get something for nothing.

Comment: @Andyaka: you're right about not being EE; I've asked that this question be moved to Physics (because just being told about conventional notions here explains nothing)

Comment: It doesn't matter how many complications or variations you add to the proposed solution; the answer is always the same: no process produces more energy output than it requires as input.

Comment: You have described one of the most classic "perpetual motion" schemes.  No matter how hard you work at it, though, friction wins out.

Comment: There is no such thing as a closed loop or closed system. Even at the molecular level photons are  radiating or delivering energy.

Comment: What if one uses capillarity effect to bring back water in the upper reservoir ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say you have one waterwheel with one generator attached which gives say 50% efficiency (can return 50% of the used water to the upper reservoir, all friction, heat-loss, etc, taken into account).

Got it.  Remember, generators work by turning the *power* from the input shaft into electrical energy.  The power is the speed of the wheel multiplied by the force it's pushing against (the torque of the generator, plus drag).

> Now you add 2 more generators to the waterwheel's elongated axle: the output of two of these generators will return 100% of the water

No, it won't.  The additional generators will (assuming they're collecting power) place additional drag on the wheel.  It will slow down and all the generators will draw less power.  The sum of the collected power by all the generators will be less than the input power from the falling water.

> and the output of the third is available for use. There can be a cascading set of waterwheels each with generators attached..
> Why would this not work, what am I not seeing?

Every collecting generator is more drag.  They can't be attached for free.

> Wasn't it Archimedes who said something about a long-enough lever and a place to stand and he will move the earth? Meaning that a small input (muscle-power in this case) can have much larger output. A waterwheel is nothing less than a lever, and so are the gears,

That is the cite, but he didn't say how far he could move it.  Levers let you trade force against distance, or in the case of a generator, rotational speed against torque.   We can lower the torque so the water spins the wheel faster.  But power is the product of speed and torque. The levers don't let us make them both bigger at the same time.

Comment: now this is a nice ELI5(see reddit) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is electrical resistance and conservation of energy and friction. You lose force due to mill friction. You lose electrical energy due to electrical resistance. Lets say you have 25% of the energy left. You would need 100% to lift the water back to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can totally build the described contraption and it will probably even run.

It will however, not run indefinitely.

"feeding the grid" means to take energy out of the system, which means it will eventually stop its operation and that assumes a machinery without any other "losses" (see @Jimmy360's answer on that)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but not 100% efficient, so you will always get back less power than you put into it - at best, maybe 80% with a large-scale plant designed for best efficiency.

So why would you want to?

If you can buy electricity at 3p/kWh overnight, and sell it at 30p/kWh during the early evening peak demand, then even factoring in the losses, that's good business.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes. It's indeed possible. The long answer however says that even though it works, it cannot work perpetually unless you continue to add water. The main energy loss in a system like this is due to water evaporation. Technically adding water to it is like adding energy. You still have to follow the laws of thermodynamics. It's not free energy if u have to continuously add something to the system for it to run.